# Unable to run fresh kotlin multiplatform app on ios

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Doing a fresh install of a kotlin multiplatform app I am unable to get the ios app to run. Android works just fine. My issue is Android Studio is unable to find xcode project schemes.

Following the tutorial from kotlin lang website get started it seems like it should just be able to run: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html#run-on-a-different-iphone-simulated-device.

[image]

Here are my versions:
Android Studio: 4.1.1
Xcode: 12.2 (12B45b)

EDIT 1:

Here is the error mentioned in the configuration page of android studio:

Please check specified Xcode project file: can't grab Xcode schemes with /usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/ommitedforbrevity/./iosApp/iosApp.xcodeproj -list

EDIT 2:

Log also shows several errors like this: TextMate bundle load error: Bundle mdx can't be registered

I confirmed that the bundled plugin TextMate Bundles is included and enabled.

Comment: You are going to need to supply some more info, works just fine for me.

Comment: @NathanSchwermann updated with error code. Is there something else you can think of that would help with resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you started Xcode by itself? It'll probably install some things.

Comment: Yes I have created several small projects in xcode. I also opened the iosApp in xcode and built it successfully. One thing that I found was my xcode cli was not configured in xcode preferences. Even after setting that and building in android studio I am still unable to select xcode scheme.

Comment: Enabling xcode CLI should help. If it won't help, try executing the command manually. Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41691

Comment: I recreated the project after I enabled Xcode CLI and it built first try. The link provided did the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: When creating the new project, in the setup wizard, change the "iOS framework distribution' from 'CocoaPods dependency manager' to 'Regular Framework'.